# Why does Yarn work for me only in one folder, but otherwise I get an unexpected EOF?

Tags: react-native, path, node-modules, yarnpkg

We had to do a lot of fiddling with certificates and such to get yarn to work in our environment.

Eventually it worked, but recently I've realized it only works in the one React Native project directory I spend all my time in.

If I try to use yarn in any other folder, it ALWAYS times out with the unexpected EOF.

If I rename a new folder to the folder name that works (and temp name the project folder) then yarn works, so there's nothing special about the directory itself.

Is there a location dependency of some kind for yarn?